# ¿Que nivel de encapsulamiento tienen los atributos de las clases en que se programa la logica de una activity en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

soy nuevo en programar para Android en Java, he estado mirando uno que otro tutorial para aprender. Se que cada activity viene compuesta por un archivo .xml en donde se describe los componentes que tendrá la activity y una clase en Java donde se programa la lógica de cada uno de estos componentes.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_buscarSala;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}
```

hasta donde tengo entendido, los componentes que se van a utilizar en la activity se declaran en la clase antes de instanciarlos en los posibles métodos que tenga la clase. Igual que cualquier atributo normal de una clase en java.

Mi pregunta es, estos "atributos" (como el objeto Button en el ejemplo) que nivel de encapsulamiento tienen? y hay alguna convención de buenas practicas que diga como se deben definir?

debería declararlos como *private* o eso produciría algún tipo de error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las activities programadas en Java deben seguir las directivas de buenas prácticas de este lenguaje, estas mismas dicen que ningún elemento puede llegar a tener un nivel de encapsulamiento **public**, su nivel de encapsulamiento debe ser **protected** o **private**.

Por otro lado, los componentes no deben ser accesibles de forma directa, es decir, no debe existir un getButtonFoo(), estos componentes pueden interactuar con el medio exterior de forma indirecta, es decir, mediante servicios o escuchadores.